# Ruby on Rails ActionMailer SMTP Settings mTLS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, mtls

How would you setup a mTLS connection for action mailer in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 3):

ActionMailer leverages the [Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) to sent mails via SMTP, which in turn uses the [net-smtp gem](https://github.com/ruby/net-smtp).

Now, while the net-smtp gem in principal supports to configure mutual TLS by specifying custom parameters for its SSLContext, this capability is [not exposed](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/10a4443b9d4ffa71b9ad643ad86cc23ccc99f0f3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb#L174-L188) by the Mail gem and thus is not available directly to ActionMailer.

Thus, it is currently not possible to configure mutual TLS with the Mail gem nor with ActionMailer out-of-the-box.